# Customize UINavigationBar with inset image

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar

[image: customNavBar]

I have this navigation bar I am trying to implement that looks like this:
I know I can either put the image directly in the nav bar or as a header image below it, but I have no idea how to inset it so that it is contained in both the main container view and breaching the navigation bar as well.

Any ideas would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's achievable using two images:

1. **background**: will match the navigation bar frame

[image]

2. **icon**: let's say an image 50x50 centered to the background in x-axis and y-axis with offset of its height / 2.0

[image]

Then you may try to use autolayout constraints doing so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let navbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar else {return} // be sure to have defined a navigation controller
        navbar.clipsToBounds = false // so the icon will be visible outside the nav bar

        let niceBkg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bkg"))
        navbar.addSubview(niceBkg)
        niceBkg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        niceBkg.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        niceBkg.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        niceBkg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.navigationController!.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        niceBkg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navbar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        let niceIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "icon"))
        niceBkg.addSubview(niceIcon)
        niceIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        niceIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        niceIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        niceIcon.centerXAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: niceBkg.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        niceIcon.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: niceBkg.bottomAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    }
}
```

on iPhoneX the result is:

[image]

---

About your scenario, you probably need only the icon and a navigationBar with a proper background color. However I added both autolayout configurations because might be useful for someone else, especially if the navigationBar's background is quite complex with border, decorations and so on.